# Как правильно: "ему стукнул полтинник" или "ему стукнуло полтинник"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

“Ему стукнул полтинник” или “ему стукнуло полтинник”?

Comment: Вы в текст вопроса напишите все-таки что-нибудь содержательное. Он же в таком виде подлежит немедленному удалению. Хотя бы сам вопрос продублируйте.

Comment: Придётся( Плохо, что обязательно нужно заполнять всё, да ещё определённой длины. Вроде весь вопрос поместился в заголовке, казалось бы, зачем дублировать или ещё что-то сочинять, если всё сформулировал. А вы не можете ничего изменить, чтобы это не было обязательным, да и разрешить новичкам писать комментарии?

Comment: Ну неужели настолько трудно, чтобы мышкой скопировать?!

Comment: Совсем не трудно, просто немного глупо повторяться (особенно точь-в-точь). ;)

Comment: *А вы не можете ничего изменить, чтобы это не было обязательным, да и разрешить новичкам писать комментарии?* - Нет, **я** не могу. ))) Это к Николаю Чабановскому. Выскажите свое пожелание на Мете.

Comment: *Совсем не трудно, просто немного глупо повторяться* - Это не глупо. Во-первых, название и текст не дополняют друг друга "по умолчанию", первое идет в список вопросов, например, второе - это собственно то, на что отвечают. Во-вторых, они даже по-разному индексируются, разными поисковыми алгоритмами.

Comment: А, ну хорошо, убедили.)) Спасибо, что сказали, теперь буду знать, что Николай за это отвечает.

Comment: Николай здесь единственный, кто за что-то отвечает. Админ, создатель и фактический владелец ресурса. Выше него - только сами система стек-эксченджа, но они конкретными вещами не занимаются, насколько знаю. А все остальные тут - на общих правах.

Comment: Во как, аж так! Буду знать) Может, при случае ему спасибо скажу. Кстати, я как вы думаете, правильно "стукнул" или стукнуло"?

Comment: Ответил там про стукнуло.

Comment: Спасибо!*******

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ***стукнуло*** - сказуемое безличного предложения, то пятьдесят или полтинник - уже неважно. "Стучат" не они. Поэтому *стукнуло*.

Если же ***стукнуло*** - личный глагол, то тогда ***полтинник стукнул***.

Я склонна думать, что в таких предложениях ***стукнуло*** - глагол личный. Ср.: *исполнилось. Один годик исполнился.* [Один годик стукнул.] Так не говорят, но по форме всё правильно.

Значит, **полтинник стукнул.**

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина!

Answer (score 1):

Все верно у Екатерины. Безличным глагол в подобном контексте может быть только при числительном, прямо отвечающем на вопрос "сколько?" - ***Пятьдесят лет стукнуло.*** Но ***"полтинник стукнул"***.

Замените "полтинник" на "(полу)сотня", "шестой десяток" или что-то подобное. И все станет предельно ясно. Ну явно же не ***"сотня стукнуло"***. Даже Niemand (которому "всё равно") вряд ли такое выговорит.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь не буду сомневаться!) Просто меня смущало, что он сам стучит, не был уверен, что так и есть.

Comment: *Даже Niemand...* Дорогой @behemothus, я знаю, что вы меня любите, но все равно это вам не поможет лучше знать язык. Хо-хо?

Comment: @Niemand, я знаю, что Вы неравнодушны к моему мнению о Вас, но уверяю, я не способен на личные к вам чувства. Мне на Вас в личном плане решительно наплевать. Единственная просьба: не использовать более ко мне эпитет "дорогой". Это калька с английского - и никак не поможет Вам доказать, что Вы знаете язык, скорее наоборот. Честь имею.

Comment: @Niemand, если же вас интересует упоминание Вас в моем тексте, то оно объяснялось не вашими ко мне чувствами, как бы того Вам не хотелось,  а вполне естественной реакцией на Ваше "всё равно", о чем я вполне недвусмысленно написал в скобках. Если угодно объясниться на эту тему - я к Вашим услугам.

Answer (score 1):

**Стукнуло.** (о годах) - иноск.: пробило, исполнилось (**намек на стукало, клепало сторожей - на бой часов, указывающих вре**мя). Ср. Вот уж стукнуло нашему барону и за сорок.

Из словаря

**Разг. Наступить (о времени, событии)**. Стукнул 1917 год. Стукнул год войны. Стукнул уже год службы в армии. **кому-чему**. **безл**. **Исполниться (о летах, о возрасте)**. Ему двадцать стукнуло. Бабушке стукнуло семьдесят. Ей скоро стукнет тридцать. Институту стукнуло пятьдесят лет.

**Примеры**

В 1862 году Ибсен к этому времени не был юношей ― ему **стукнуло** 33 года...

И когда Юре Никулину **стукнул полтинник**, мы с Зямой взгромоздились на сцену ЦДРИ с куплетами в честь великого клоуна. [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000).

Но маленькому принцу, которому десять дней тому назад **стукнул год**, она, разумеется, должна казаться роскошной. [Л. А. Чарская. Мой принц (1915)]

Таким образом, **практически** личная форма используется только с отдельными существительным м. р. с числовым значением (год, полтинник).

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla! Понятно, интересно.

Answer (score 0):

В предложении явно разговорного характера это все равно.

Comment: Мне всё-таки хочется чем-то руководствоваться и в таких (разговорных) случаях. Вот Екатерина же рассудила как-то.

Comment: Рассудила, и по ее рассуждениям тоже оба варианта допустимы.

Comment: Она сказала, что логика может быть теоретически разная, но реально смысл вкладывают какой-то один, т. е. образовалось выражение в определённом смысле, только вот сейчас понять точно сложно, но ей кажется, что по второму её варианту, когда полтинник "сам" "стучит". А кто-то, может, совсем уверен и объяснит почему.

Comment: *Она сказала, что логика может быть теоретически разная* - ну да. Верная и неверная. И она сказала еще и то, какая логика ей кажется верной. А Niemand придерживается принципа "Прапор сказал -  солдат сделал". Поэтому к нему и отношение такое. Более того, он еще и переврал смысл сказанного Екатериной. Нет, по её рассуждениям совсем не "оба варианта допустимы". Во всяком случае, не ***одинаково*** допустимы.